# SSRF through image searching function?

Tags: ssrf

I am testing this site which has a feature where a user can enter a URL, and the site will grab all images from that URL and allow the user to use them on the site.

This is my first time looking for SSRF so I'm not fully sure what counts as a vulnerability or not, I've made a script that when a user visits my site, it grabs their IP address and renders it as an image on the same page. I've found this works and leaks the webservers IP address back to the user but I'm not sure if this would be that much of a problem.

Does this count as a vulnerability (maybe information leakage)? Using this same method is there any other sensitive information that I could try to access from the web server to gain a higher severity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not a SSRF vulnerability since accessing publicly available remote images is the intended feature of the site. It would be a SSRF if one would be able to access private web sites, i.e. internal sites accessible to the web server but not directly accessible by the public.

It is probably not an information leak either since it likely only reveals the public IP address of the web server - which is publicly known anyway.